# How convert iOS core motion in PWM

Tags: ios, pwm

I would use my Iphone accelerometer and gyro coupled with Arduino. For my project I need to provide data to arduino code about iphone accelerometer and gyro (roll, pitch, yaw) in the PWM 'format'. I have read some iOS documentation and from iOS core motion library seem I can access only rotation matrix, euler and quaternion representation of motion data. Do you can suggest me a solution to obtain PWM values?

Best,

Lucio

Comment: Do you have more information about the PWM format that you're talking about?

Comment: @joerick Unfortunately no, because I'm using third part library (on arduino) to read pwm signals as its input.

Comment: that sounds unlikely, [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) is a way of representing an analog signal using a digital output. What's the library called, and does it have any documentation?

Comment: the library is aeroquad (http://code.google.com/p/aeroquad/downloads/list)